# Remote printing from ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have Konica Bizhub C368 that we are trying to print from via an ec2 instance. 
We are using NAT translation on our Sonicwall to forward a port on our public IP to the LAN ip of the printer.

We've tested it from a non-aws network at a two different remote locations. In both cases, it works. From the AWS side, we are able to get a test print from a Linux instance via CUPS.

However, any actual document we send will a connection time out error. What should we be looking at to try and solve this?

Comment: What's the difference between a test print and sending an actual document? Is there a difference in ports used? Do you have all ports open or only specific ports? Have you tried using curl to the printer web interface from Linux - what happens? Basically I'm asking for a bit more detail and diagnostic information, that will help people offer more help.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a simple network transfer works (ie short test page) but long one with the same settings doesn’t (ie full document) it smells like a **[MTU issue](https://netbeez.net/blog/troubleshooting-mtu-issues/)** - probably somewhere on your Sonicwall side or the links around I’d guess.

Do some testing and research in that direction.

Hope that helps :)